# How to click on the element using the innerText text of a class in Selenium vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am willing to get the innerText and click on it. The text is *Customer Service Inquiry*.

I have tried:

```
.FindElementsByXPath("//*[text()[contains(.listItem, 'Customer Service Inquiry')]]").Click
```

This does not work as it gives error that it is not a valid xpath expression

Further, this works but I am wanting to click by what the inner text says.

```
.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='listFav_ALLOUTSECURITY0000000000000000008276_APP_P4210_W4210E_PSG0021_20']").click
```

The html

```
<div id="listContentHolder"> == $0 > <div class="carolist" id="listOCL" slot="0" style="height: 57px; top: @px;">.</div> > <div class="carolist" id="listRecipts" slot="1" style="height: 57px; top: 57px;">.</div> <div class="caroList" id="listFav" slot="2" style="height: 153px; top: 114px;"> > <div class="listHeader expanded" id="listFavHeader" oncontextmenu="javascript:CARO.updateDropdownMenuView(this,event);jdebebGUIdoToggleSubMenu(this,'caroTabContextMenu', event, true)
;" toplistitem="false">.</div> <div id="listFavouter" class="listContentOuter" style="height: 128px;"> <div id="listFavInner" class="listContentInner" style="height: 128px; top: Opx;">
<div class="listItem" id="listFav_manageFavs" aria-labelledby="appCaption_fav_manageFavs" role="link" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none; top: Opx;">.</div> > <div class="listItem" id="listFav_ALLOUTSECURITY0000000000000000008582_APP_P4210_W4210E_PSG0099_10" aria-labelledby="appCaption_fav_ALLOUTSECURITY0000000000000000008582_APP_P4210_W 4210E_PSG0099_10" role="link" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none; top: 32px;">.</div> 

<div class="listItem" id="listFav_ALLOUTSECURITY0000000000000000008276_APP_P4210_W4210E_PSG0021_20" aria-labelledby="appCaption_fav_ALLOUTSECURITY0000000000000000008276_APP_P4210_W 4210E_PSG0021_20" role="link" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none; top: 64px;"> <table class="listItem"> 
<tbody>
<tr> > 
<td class="listIcon">.</td>
<td class="listText">Customer Service Inquiry</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> 
</div> 

<div class="listItem" id="listFav_21343ad6_1803cf57c8c__7ffeE1PDJAS3__APP_P41026_W41026E_PSA0001_30" aria-labelledby="appCaption_fav_21343ad6_1803cf57c8c__7ffeE1PDJAS3_APP_P41026_ W41026E_PSA0001_30" role="link" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none; top: 96px;">.</div> </div> <a class="panControl up" necessary="false" style></a>
<a class="panControl down" necessary="false" stylex/a> </div> </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as ***Customer Service Inquiry*** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *FindElementByXPath* and only the *innerText*:

  ```
  .FindElementByXPath("//td[text()='Customer Service Inquiry']").click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath* along with the *class* and the *innerText*:

  ```
  .FindElementByXPath("//td[@class='listText' and text()='Customer Service Inquiry']").click
  ```